# MacOs OpenGl forward compatibilty?

Tags: macos, opengl, f#, opentk

I am trying to set up some very simple graphic windows which I also have to use on MacOS version Big Sur unfortunately. I am using the F# programming language and the OpenTK package.

This is the code I have at the moment.

```
open OpenTK.Windowing.Desktop
open OpenTK.Mathematics
open OpenTK.Windowing.Common
open OpenTK.Graphics


[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let prof = ContextProfile.Compatability
    let windowSettings = NativeWindowSettings()
    windowSettings.Size <- Vector2i(800, 600)
    windowSettings.Title <- "OpenTK Window"
    windowSettings.Profile <- prof
    windowSettings.APIVersion <- Version "3.3"
    use window = new GameWindow(GameWindowSettings.Default, windowSettings)
    //window.MakeCurrent()
    //window.Run ()

    0
```

Whenever I run this I get:

```
Unhandled exception. OpenTK.Windowing.GraphicsLibraryFramework.GLFWException: NSGL: The targeted version of macOS only supports forward-compatible core profile contexts for OpenGL 3.2 and above
   at OpenTK.Windowing.Desktop.GLFWProvider.<>c.<.cctor>b__5_0(ErrorCode errorCode, String description)
```

I have tried every single configuration possible but I am stumped, is there anyone that can give me a pointer on how to set the compatibility for this?

Answer (score 1):

Change this

> ```
> let prof = ContextProfile.Compatability
> ```

to

```
let prof = ContextProfile.Core
```